# Matlab DICOM Slices

Tags: image, matlab, slice, dicom

I have a DICOM image loaded as a matrix in matlab. My question is, how do I show specific slices of that image in each orthogonal direction?

Like view slice x at position 100, y=0, z=0

Comment: I'm not familiar with DICOM, but you just defined a point in 3D (x=100,y=0,z=0), what do you mean by a slice? If you try in matlab to 'size(image)' what do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your matrix is M, and has d dimensions (3, or what have you) and you want to plot a 1-D "slice" of one of the dimensions then:

```
  plot(squeeze(M(n1,n2, ...,:,...));
```

where n1,n2,... are the positions of dimension x,y,... where you want to slice, and the operator (:) is the dimension you want to plot.

for example, given a 5 dimensional matrix  M=rand(10,10,10,10,10), lets slice the 4-th dimension around some points (x=n1, y=n2, etc...)

```
   M=rand(10,10,10,10,10);
   n1=4; n2=7; n3=3; n5=5; 
   plot(squeeze(M(n1,n2, n3, :, n5)));
```

If the slice is 2-D then you can use imshow or imagesc to show the 2-D slice, for example showing the 2-nd and 4-th dimension:

```
 imagesc(squeeze(M(n1,:,n3,:,n5)))
```